# Biscuits in a container probability problem.

Tags: probability

I want to take out biscuits from a container. There are 3 different kinds of biscuits: A, B, and C. The probability to take A is 0.6, to take B is 0.3, and to take C is 0.1. If I were to take 2 biscuits randomly from the container, what is the probability that I took C out of the container?

My approach was to find
$1 - P(A \ and \ B)$ , but I had problems trying to figure out the right way to find $P(A \ and \ B)$. My first approach was $P(A \ and \ B)=\frac{6}{10} \times \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{10} \times \frac{6}{7}$ but the answer was not included in the multiple choice.

The choices were: 0.1, 0.19, 0.33, 0.36, and 0.18.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $0.19$. The are 5 ways you can draw $C$:

$[C,C], [C,B],[C,A],[A,C],[B,C]$. So the probability to draw $C$ is the addition of these cases:

$0.1 \times 0.1 + 0.1 \times 0.6 \times 2 + 0.3 \times 0.1 \times 2=0.19 $